# PHP include with pure HTML only

Tags: php, include

I'd like to know the opinion of you PHP savvys on this one. I'm still a very novice programmer, so bear with me:

- Is it safe/correct to use **PHP include** of PHP files with **pure HTML content** inside them)?

I'm asking this because I had a bitter experience with AJAX load() some months ago, not loading external css and script files.

Comment: Why don't you use `readfile()` instead?

Comment: "safe" in what way, where are the files coming from? If they're coming from an untrusted source, then the answer is no - they could contain malicious PHP code that gets executed by your include. If they're *your* files, using `include()` is fine.

Comment: @ Pekka웃 They are my files.

Comment: If they're your own files so you know you can trust them and use `include()`, it will include any javascript and CSS

Comment: However, unless you are going to include php code later on, you could probably just use Server Side Includes and just include an html file. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html

Comment: If the pure html file contains `<?` or `<?php` (as php code example), then the code could be executed.

Answer (score 1):

tldr: **Yes**

you can think of `include` as of a template engine, mean to copy-paste piece into your document. It's perfect for simple cases. For complex you might be better with real template engines like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org)